# Не срабатывает padding сверху. Masonry

Tags: jquery, css

Нас последнем экране товаров не получается сделать отступ сверху. 
Использовал плагин Masonry для адаптивной плитки блоков. 
Блоки тянуться как нужно, но вылезают за фиксированное меню. Плагин вешает в `html` свою высоту контейнера. Возможно, это из-за размеров заданной высоты блоков в `vh` единицах, но, использую проценты, блоки слипаются.
В чем может быть проблема и как ее можно решить?
Спасибо.
[Линк](http://atomr-web.github.io/lamar/)

```
    <div id="products">
    <div class="products__container">
        <div class="products__catalog">
            <div class="products__item products__item--height2">
                <div class="products__item_title-wrapper">
                    <div class="products__item_title_line"></div>
                    <div class="products__item_title">sabre</div>
                    <div class="products__item_title_line"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="products__item_text">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, tempore!
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="products__item_mask"></div>
                <img src="img/catalog/sabre.png" alt="" class="products__item_bg">
            </div>
            <div class="products__item products__item--width2">
                <div class="products__item_title-wrapper">
                    <div class="products__item_title_line"></div>
                    <div class="products__item_title">dirk</div>
                    <div class="products__item_title_line"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="products__item_text">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, tempore!
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="products__item_mask"></div>
                <img src="img/catalog/dirk.png" alt="" class="products__item_bg">
            </div>
            <div class="products__item">
                <div class="products__item_title-wrapper">
                    <div class="products__item_title_line"></div>
                    <div class="products__item_title">walking stick</div>
                    <div class="products__item_title_line"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="products__item_text">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, tempore!
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="products__item_mask"></div>
                <img src="img/catalog/walking_stick.png" alt="" class="products__item_bg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#products {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.products__container {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.products__container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.products__catalog {
  width: 100%;
}

.products__catalog:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.products__item {
  width: calc(25% - 15px);
  height: -moz-calc(33.33vh - 15px);
  height: -webkit-calc(33.33vh - 15px);
  height: calc(33.33vh - 15px);
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.products__item--height2 {
  height: -moz-calc(66.3333vh - 15px);
  height: -webkit-calc(66.3333vh - 15px);
  height: calc(66.3333vh - 15px);
}

.products__item--width2 {
  width: calc(50% - 15px);
}
```

JQ

```
$('.products__catalog').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.products__item',
  gutter: 12,
  percentPosition: true
});
```

Comment: Я вот ничего не понял. Masonry вешает высоту на тот блок, который ты указал в качестве контейнера для элементов, а именно `products__catalog`. Посмотри, у него высота фиксирована.

Comment: А секция сверху с id about у тебя 100vh, поэтому так высоко. А проценты - наследуемая единица, так что тут уже копать в коде нужно, которого ни черта нет.

Comment: Если двигать высоту окна, то у тебя не только сетка слипается если что :D Ты бы всё заного пересверстал касательно высоты и адаптивности, переосмысление бы сделал, было бы куда лучше.

Comment: @VostokSisters на сколько я понимаю, каждому экрану нужно задавать высоту в 100vh. И секция `main` также, как и `about` так же задан 100vh. Если двигать высоту экрана - да, сетка слипается, но если обновить - все норм. А что именно и в каком направлении по другому вы имеете ввиду переделать?

Comment: Стоит перенести html и css  в тело вопроса, подготовив минимальный воспроизводимый пример согласно правилам сайта.

Comment: @atomr, задай хотя бы тогда минимальную высоту каждой секции, чтобы не слипалась в нулину.

Comment: @VostokSisters это да, на локалке уже добавил. Но как быть с сеткой? Можешь подсказать, пожалуйста? Код добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело было в элементе кода, где описывается плавное перемещение по экранам.

```
var lastId,
  topMenu = $("#menu"),
  topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight() - 135,
  // All list items
  menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
  // Anchors corresponding to menu items
  scrollItems = menuItems.map(function() {
    var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
    if (item.length) {
      return item;
    }
  });
```

Нужно было изменить значение `topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight() - 135`